# How do I access npm log files in GKE?

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running different nodejs microservices on Google Kubernetes Services.
Sometimes these services crash and according to Cloud Logging, I can find detailed information in a logging file. For example, the logging message says

```
{
  "textPayload": "npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-27T11_26_28_534Z-debug.log\n",
  "insertId": "zoqxk8wvkuofhslm",
  "resource": {
    "type": "k8s_container",
    "labels": {
      "pod_name": "client-depl-7f679c6b49-5d9tz",
      "container_name": "client",
      "namespace_name": "production",
      "cluster_name": "cluster-1",
      "location": "europe-west3-a",
      "project_id": "XXX"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-10-27T11:26:28.701252670Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "k8s-pod/app": "client",
    "k8s-pod/skaffold_dev/run-id": "b5518659-05d6-4c08-9b55-9d58fdd5807f",
    "k8s-pod/pod-template-hash": "7f679c6b49",
    "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "gke-cluster-1-pool-1-8bfc60b2-ag86",
    "k8s-pod/app_kubernetes_io/managed-by": "skaffold"
  },
  "logName": "projects/xxx-productive/logs/stderr",
  "receiveTimestamp": "xxx"
}
```

Where do I find these logs on Google Cloud Platform?

---------------- Edit 2021.10.28 ---------------------------

I should clarify that I am already using the logs explorer. This is what I see there:
[image: Logs Explorer showing npm error]

The logs show 7 consecutive error entries about npm failing. The last two entries indicate that there are more information in a log file "/root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-27T11_26_28_534Z-debug.log".
Does this log file has more info about the failure or is all the info I get in these 7 error log entries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. kubectl logs <your_pod>
2. You can use GCP Logs Explorer
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question to clarify that I am already using Logs Explorer and to better explain the problem with the missing log.

Answer (score 1):

How to login to a GCP Pod:

1. From the Google Cloud Platform main menu go to **Kubernetes Engine** -> **Workloads**
2. Click on the workload you're interested in:
   [image: workloads]
3. Find the Managed Pods section and click on the Pod you want to access:
   [image: managed pods]
4. Click on **KUBECTL -> Exec -> [name of workload/namespace]**
   [image]
5. A terminal should appear at the bottom of the browser page, SSHing you into the pod. You can look around for your log file from inside here

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already [Enable Logging and Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/on-prem/1.5/how-to/application-logging-monitoring#enabling_and_for_user_applications), You can view logs on:

a. Go to the **Logs explorer** in the Cloud Console.

b. Click Resource. Under **ALL_RESOURCE_TYPES**, select `Kubernetes Container`.

c. Under **CLUSTER_NAME**, select the name of your user cluster.

d. Under NAMESPACE_NAME, select default.

e. Click Add and then click Run Query.

f. Under Query results, you can see log entries from the monitoring-example Deployment. For example:

> {
> "textPayload": "2020/11/14 01:24:24 Starting to listen on :9090\n", 
> "insertId": "1oa4vhg3qfxidt", 
> "resource": { 
> "type": "k8s_container", 
> "labels": { 
> "pod_name": "monitoring-example-7685d96496-xqfsf", 
> "cluster_name": ..., 
> "namespace_name": "default", 
> "project_id": ..., 
> "location": "us-west1", 
> "container_name": "prometheus-example-exporter" 
> } 
> },
> "timestamp": "2020-11-14T01:24:24.358600252Z", 
> "labels": { 
> "k8s-pod/pod-template-hash": "7685d96496", 
> "k8s-pod/app": "monitoring-example" 
> }, 
> "logName": "projects/.../logs/stdout", 
> "receiveTimestamp": "2020-11-14T01:24:39.562864735Z" 
> }

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question to clarify that I am already using Logs Explorer and to better explain the problem with the missing log.

Answer (score 0):

How about

- log into the pod while it is alive

  *kubectl exec -it **your-pod** -- sh*
- wait for it to crash and watch the crash file in real time while the pod is not restarted yet :)

Comment: The error occurs when the pod tries to restart at which point I cannot connect to it. Thanks